# Netty Server login , encoder handler and decoder handler logic , should be replicated in the client code?

Tags: netty

if i have customized logic in my Netty server encoder, decoder, and handshake handlers, and i have a TCP client written in pure java NIO, is it must to replicate my server encoder, decoder and handshake handler logic in a client specific handlers, to not lose any packets or streams, which leads to closing the opened channels?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well all you need to take care of is that the server and client speak the same protocol. How you implement it is up to you. Just remember network programming does only send / receive bytes at the low level. So you can implement it with different programming languages.